# javascript onclick without call function directly get value

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Click the button".</p>
        <input type="text" name="demo" id="demo" value="">
        <button value="button" onclick="alert(document.getElementById("demo").value);">Click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code is not working but `document.getElementById("demo").value` replace "this.value" getting result "button".

may be any syntax error or this way of onclick is not working?

Comment: `onclick="alert(document.getElementById('demo').value);"` - use of 2 sets of `"` is causing the issue

Comment: working fine thank

Comment: Using JQuery : <button value="button" onclick="alert($('#demo').val());">Click me</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quotes instead and that will works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the button".</p>
<input type="text" name="demo" id="demo" value="">
<button value="button" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('demo').value);">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```